# Using f(x) = 1/x in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algebra

Every millisecond, variable *light* is incremented by one until it reaches 1/3rd of variable *universe*, or until it's 3 times the variable *matter*.

```
if (light < (universe * (1/3)) || light < matter * 3 && light <= universe) {
        light++;
    }
```

Instead, I want light to increase slower the closer it gets to the top,
(*1/3rd universe* or *3 * matter*)
like [this picture](http://zonalandeducation.com/mmts/functionInstitute/rationalFunctions/oneOverX/pic1.gif) ( *f(x) = 1/x* ).

How do I do this?

Comment: Instead of `light++` why not use `light += d` where `d` is some value that diminishes?

Comment: f = function(x){ return 1/(x); };     light += f(light);

Comment: So is my anwser what your trying to achieve George?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
var speed = 10;
var target = Math.max(universe / 3, Math.min(universe, matter * 3));
if (light < target) {
  light += (target - light) / speed;
}
```

Comment: This makes sense, but wouldn't it still increase light by the same amount every iteration?

Comment: No, because `target - light` changes in each iteration. There's a joke about this: A psychologist asks a physicist and a mathematician to an experiment. "I'll place a naked lady on the bed in this corner, and tie you to a chair in the opposite corner. Every 10 minutes I'll move you halfway to the bed." Mathematician walks out angrily: "You know we'll *never* reach that bed!" The physicist grins. "Why are you so eager? Doesn't what he said make sense?" asks the psychologist; the physicist answers "Close enough for all practical purposes!"

Comment: This method is coming along well. I increased speed to 100 which, for some reason, works a lot better. Works! Thank you!!! (This is my first stackExchange question, I appreciate it)

Comment: Hold up a second... light doesn't increase until matter is added. How do I fix that?

Comment: Ah, I misread your question (`||`, not `&&`!); replacing `min` with `max` should fix it.

Comment: You're great. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to make sure that `light` is a floating point variable, the `++` operator would usually used just for integers.
2. You just need to add on `1/light` on each iteration

-

```
var light = 0.0;

if (...) {
    light += 1/light;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you. At the moment it returns "Infinity" but probably because var light is global or something like that.

Comment: True, my mistake. I want _light_ to never reach the top (1/3rd _universe_). What do I do to prevent it from reaching 1/3rd? Or to make it increase more slowly over time?

Answer (score 0):

So here speed starts out by 100, and then i added a interval so it continues every 1000milliseconds/1second and it will go on.

```
 (function(){
      setInterval(function(){
      var speed= 99999999;
        if(light<(universe/3) || light<(matter*3) && light <= universe)){
          light+=speed;
          speed--;
        }
      },1000)
    })()
```

And Yes.. [**`Infinty`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity) is a keyword in javascript.

Comment: After 10 seconds, _speed_ reaches zero and light no longer increases.

Comment: Then how many seconds do you want @GeorgePowell ?  I went according to your pic which was a 10 interval..

Comment: The picture was to demonstrate how the lines never reach the x or y axis, similar to how light should never reach _universe * 1/3_ or _matter * 3_.

Comment: No, because _light_ plus _Infinity_ is still _Infinity_, and _Infinity_ minus _one_ is also still infinity.

Comment: Ok then... You obviously said : `the lines never reach the x or y axis,`... If you want a higher number you can just type a higher number like im about to do in 3seconds @GeorgePowell